# pixel tracking execute js

Tags: javascript, cookies, pixel, tracking

The flow we defined for a pixel tracking is the following:

1. User visits our ourpage.com, we set cookies, redirect to ecommerce.com
2. Ecommerce.com buy page request a pixel to us (ourpage.com/pixel.gif?brand=1)
3. In ourpage.com we process the request and execute a script to check if has cookies and query params. If true, we perform a post to our service.

The **doubt** is, in the ecommerce.com page we have an img that calls to ourpage.com, but we want to execute in ourpage.com (where the cookies rest) a js code that validates cookies and query params and performs a post to our service.

I've tried creating a .gif file as "...checkcookies()..." with no success. Also embeding js code inside the gif as [here](http://iamajin.blogspot.com.es/2014/11/when-gifs-serve-javascript.html) suggests.

I've looked information about this, but don't really get how to execute my js code in ourpage.com by calling a .gif.

Thanks!

Comment: cookies are send in the request header no need to use javascript. Also i guess ecommerce.com won't be happy if you xss atack them.

Comment: the js code is in ourpage.com, and needs to be executed there to check cookies, and I need to use js to check that cookies follow some requirements. All ecommerce sites have pixels, I want to add mine, maybe I'm not performing the correct aproach... but don't now which would that be otherwise

Comment: is the pixel included with an `img` tag? then you have no cance. Even if no and you would be able to execute JavaScript on `ecommerce.com`, you could only read cookies from `ecommerce.com` and not from `ourpage.com`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm aware of that. The thing is that I want to execute the code in `ourpage.com`, called from `ecommerce.com` as other pixels do. 
How is it done otherwise? How do they track? they are calling an image to their domain to read the cookies there, and perform operations.

Comment: you can easily read/write the cookies and query params with a server side language at `ourpage.com/pixel.gif`

Comment: That's the last option we have in the list, since that would be very expensive executing all queries to our service. The clients in which we add our pixel generate a lot of sales per day since they are main ecommerces.

Comment: the only other options i could think of is asking `ecommerce.com` to include an `iframe` or `script` tag instead of an `img` tag. But checking cookies and query params won't let your server explode i think :P.

Comment: hehe The problem of doing in the server is that it will have to handle a lot of requests, and that's expensive, not the processing we need to do.
I've seen that other pixels run a js code from calling an endpoint from an image src, and wanted to implement that :S

Comment: could you show me an example? you are already handling a lot of requests: you serve gifs for each request.

Comment: It seems we are giving up and doing it on the server... :S thanks again!